# How can I animate the deletion of Rows and Sections in my TableView if I'm using a SnapshotListener?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, tableview

How can I animate the deletion of Rows and Section if I'm using a SnapshotListener which gets called every time data is added/removed. Right now when I swipe to delete, there is no animation and the rows/sections just disappear abruptly, which makes sense since I'm not implementing animation, nor am I manually removing rows/section. Here is my loadData...

```
feedback = self.rootWorkoutsCollection.addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, err) in
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            group.enter()

            self.workoutsCollection.daysCollection.removeAll()

            if let err = err
            {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err.localizedDescription)")
            }
            else {
                guard let workoutDocuments = snapshot?.documents else { return }

                for document in workoutDocuments {
                    var foundIt = false

                    let workoutData = document.data()
                    let day = workoutData["Day"] as! String
                    let workout = workoutData["Workout"] as! String

                    if self.workoutsCollection.daysCollection.isEmpty {

                        let newWorkout = Workout(Day: day, Workout: workout, Ref: document.reference)
                        let newDay = Day(Day: day, Workout: newWorkout, Ref: newWorkout.key)
                        self.workoutsCollection.daysCollection.append(newDay)
                        continue
                    }

                    if !foundIt{
                        for dayObject in self.workoutsCollection.daysCollection{
                            for dow in dayObject.workout{
                                if dow.day == day{
                                    let newWorkout = Workout(Day: day, Workout: workout, Ref: document.reference)
                                    dayObject.workout.append(newWorkout)
                                    foundIt = true
                                    break
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if foundIt == false{
                        let newWorkout = Workout(Day: day, Workout: workout, Ref: document.reference)
                        let newDay = Day(Day: day, Workout: newWorkout, Ref: newWorkout.key)
                        self.workoutsCollection.daysCollection.append(newDay)
                    }

                }

            }
            group.leave()
            group.notify(queue: .main){
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            }
        )
```

And here is the function that I'm using to remove data from the backend and locally...

```
func removeWorkout(Dow: Day, Workout: Workout ){

        let db : Firestore!
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("Users").document("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)").collection("Workouts").document(Dow.key.documentID).delete()

        if let dayIndex = daysCollection.firstIndex(of: Dow), let workoutIndex = daysCollection[dayIndex].workout.firstIndex(of: Workout) {
            daysCollection[dayIndex].workout.remove(at: workoutIndex)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to not loop over `snapshot?.documents`, but instead use `snapshot.documentChanges`. The `documentChanges` collection contains information about how each document was changed between the previous query snapshot and this one.

From the Firebase documentation on [viewing changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots):

```
db.collection("cities").whereField("state", isEqualTo: "CA")
    .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
            if (diff.type == .added) {
                print("New city: \(diff.document.data())")
            }
            if (diff.type == .modified) {
                print("Modified city: \(diff.document.data())")
            }
            if (diff.type == .removed) {
                print("Removed city: \(diff.document.data())")
            }
        }
    }
```

You can then use this extra information to animate the table view by calling `reloadRows`, `insertRows` and `deleteRows` with the documents from above.